# How Cobertura identify the branches in the code?

Tags: java, cobertura

I'm testing cobertura with my code and generated a simple report. Having a bit problem with understanding the numbers illustrated there.

[image]

There is only one class and the content is shown as in the image.
The tests I wrote is as below,

```
public class AppTest {
    @Before
    public void before() {

    }

    @Test
    public void addShouldReturnTheSumOfTwoIntegersWhenFirstIsLessThan100() {
        Assert.assertTrue(65 == App.add(20, 45));
    }

    @Test
    public void addShouldReturnMinusOneWhenFirstIsGreaterThan200() {
        Assert.assertTrue(-1 == App.add(250, 45));
    }
}
```

As shown in the image there are `4` branches. Can somebody explain how that number is `4` ?

**UPDATE :**

When I have only the below test case,

```
@Test
public void addShouldReturnMinusOneWhenFirstIsGreaterThan200() {
    Assert.assertTrue(-1 == App.add(250, 45));
}
```

output ,

[image]

And when I have all 3 tests,

```
@Test
public void addShouldReturnTheSumOfTwoIntegersWhenFirstIsLessThan100() {
    Assert.assertTrue(65 == App.add(20, 45));
}

@Test
public void addShouldReturnMinusOneWhenFirstIsGreaterThan200() {
    Assert.assertTrue(-1 == App.add(250, 45));
}

@Test
public void addShouldReturn200WhenFirstIsGreaterThan100AndLessThan200() {
    Assert.assertTrue(200 == App.add(120, 45));
}
```

output,

[image]

When I have the below test case for `return 200` branch,

```
@Test
public void addShouldReturn200WhenFirstIsGreaterThan100AndLessThan200() {
    Assert.assertTrue(200 == App.add(120, 45));
}
```

output,

[image]

**UPDATE 2 :**

If I have a test case to check the first `if` clause,

```
@Test
public void addShouldReturnTheSumOfTwoIntegersWhenFirstIsLessThan100() {
    Assert.assertTrue(65 == App.add(20, 45));
}
```

output,

[image]

I think that hidden branch is not covered by only this test case. But any other below branch will cover the mysterious branch as well.

**UPDATE 3:**

After using `javap -c App.class`,

```
Compiled from "App.java"
public class com.vnb.play_cobertura.play_cobertura.App {
public com.vnb.play_cobertura.play_cobertura.App();
Code:
   0: aload_0
   1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":
()V
   4: return

  public static int add(int, int);
Code:
   0: iload_0
   1: bipush        100
   3: if_icmpge     10
   6: iload_0
   7: iload_1
   8: iadd
   9: ireturn
  10: iload_0
  11: sipush        200
  14: if_icmpge     21
  17: sipush        200
  20: ireturn
  21: iconst_m1
  22: ireturn
}
```

De-compiled output,

```
package com.vnb.play_cobertura.play_cobertura;

public class App
{
  public App() {}

  public static int add(int a, int b)
  {
    if (a < 100)
      return a + b;
    if (a < 200) {
      return 200;
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a test of `App.add(120, 45)` with the expected output.  Just a guess, but I think you'll get `6/6` then.

Comment: @JimGarrison I did that and then it will be 4/4. So far I can identify 3 branches. I wrote 3 cases for those and problem is what is the other one ? And that other one is passed anyway as appears.

Comment: Clearly you didn't test the `return 200` branch.  If you tested all three then please show the actual code and Cobertura output.

Comment: @JimGarrison done, please check the updated question.

Comment: If there's a Cobertura forum and/or bug tracker I'd start there.  This might be a bug.  You might take a look at the output of `javap` to see if there's a hidden branch in the generated code.

Comment: I guess that this is because the compiler transforms your code to something with 4 branches.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker How to verify that ?

Comment: @JimGarrison and SpaceTrucker  please see the update 2.

Comment: Again, run `javap` on the class file for the class containing the `add()` method and examine the disassembled bytecode to see the extra branch.

Comment: @JimGarrison please look at the update 3. That is the output of `javap` , Can you suggest anything ?

Comment: It's looking at each boolean expression independently. 2 booleans * 2 states = 4 branches. The fact that there are only 3 *outcomes* is irrelevant, as is the fact that two of those boolean states are contradictory.

Comment: @shmosel can you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Not this late at night I'm afraid... unless you have a specific question.

Comment: @shmosel I actually did not get what you meant by `2 booleans * 2 states = 4 branches` , may be a bit more explanation will do. Or a resource to refer.

Comment: There are two boolean expressions (`a < 100` and `a < 200`). Each of those  independently can be true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `javap` output there are branches at instructions 3 and 14. Each of those branches is evaluated independently by cobertura. Since each branch can have two different outcomes cobertura counts 4 paths in total for your method.

In general it's not feasible for cobertura or any other tool to find all dependencies between branches. So that's why those tools don't even try to do that.

The compiler transformed your code to something more like this (note the missing `else` before the second `if`):

```
if (a < 100) {
    return a + b;
}
if (a < 200) {
    return 200;
}
return -1;
```

Comment: So you mean that cobertura wont take the `return` statements into account ?  The decompiled code looks something similar.

Comment: @prime yes, that's what I mean.